# relation between the integrals $f(x)=(\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2} dt)^2,g(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x^2(t+1)}}{t^2+1}$

Tags: riemann-integration

Is there any special relation between the integrals

$$f(x)=\left(\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2} dt\right)^2,g(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1} dt$$

as these two integrals can be used to show that,
$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t^2} dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$

Comment: Is the $t+1$ in $g$ a typo for $t^2+1$?

Comment: Yeah! You are right,sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about the third proof [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf). Since$$f^\prime(x)=-2e^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt\stackrel{y:=\frac{t}{x}}{=}-\int_0^12xe^{-(1+y^2)x^2}dy=-\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1\frac{e^{(1+y^2)x^2}}{1+y^2}dy=-g^\prime(x),$$$f+g$ is constant. Its value with $x=\infty$ is the square of the integral you want to evaluate; its value with $x=0$ is $\int_0^1\frac{dt}{t^2+1}=\frac{\pi}{4}$.